# Panda 4: Reducing #indexed pages. How much is enough?

Tags: seo, google, search-engine-indexing, noindex, google-panda-algorithm

I've been hit by panda 4 (40% decrease). I didn't see any change during panda 1-3. From what I've read it and when compared to my site, the change is probably due to the fact that I have over 30M pages indexed on Google, and they've starting seeing that as some sort of bad indication. Although I feel all of the pages have a unique value that Google should crawl, it seems I should make some tough calls and deduce the indexed pages according to some prioritization I will conduct. The question is what should be my target, or what factors should help me figure out a relevant target.

How many pages should I try to reduce to?
 - 25M
 - 15M
 - 1M
 - 2000

Is it enough to add `noindex` to low priority pages or should I also remove all internal linking to them?

UPDATE: just to clarify, all of my pages are such that I believe will provide value to my users. But as I understood, in times like these I should still consider de-indexing some of them, because just because a user might get value, doesn't mean Google will see this as a quality page, which is a very subjective definition actually.

Comment: Page number is irrelevant, Quality is.

Comment: Where are you getting your *Panda 4* information? How do you know you are being penalized? I cannot think that a large site is the problem, but perhaps content quality. After all, there are tons of huge sites such as Wikipedia that are highly prized by Google with many millions of pages.

Comment: @bybe would you say adding low quality pages to quality pages is irrelevant?

Comment: @closetnoc Just because an internet giant can get away with something doesn't mean I can.

Comment: @bybe Do you not agree there are times where a page gives value to your users but you should remove it from Googles index because he might see it as low quality?

Comment: @Noam Relax. I only asked *how* you know you were penalized by *Panda 4*. I also said that the size of the site is not the issue. I used the word *perhaps* and mentioned page quality since that seems to be a primary reason these days. But you seem to be taking offense and getting upset. I am not saying your site is not quality, I am saying that perhaps that there is a trigger (generally a keyword/phrase) that makes Google think it is low quality. Or perhaps a few pages that are thinner but still valuable. Google is a machine. Not a he/she/it or anything else.

Comment: @Noam I was asking how you decided you were hit by Panda 4. Was there a site that helped you determine this and what about your site do you think fits the Panda 4 target? I am still willing to try and figure out something specific. I was not attacking you and if that is what you felt- I am sorry. It was not my intent.

Comment: @closetnoc Hey mate, I wasn't offended, was actually just making a comment that what works for internet giants might not be true for a smaller site. Didn't mean to make it sound that way, I definitely appreciate your insights and time and it wasn't my intent either. The reason I believe I was hit by panda 4 is the day it want live I got a substantial traffic hit.

Comment: Gotca! I was concerned. It is very easy to lose context in writing small and simple comments. We cannot always get it right- trust me I know! I can understand being freaked out about a huge hit. Are you able to give use the site name?

Comment: BTW- Nice site! SEMRush shows a downward trend from Jan but leveled off in May-Jun. I take SEMRush with salt. I also see that SEMRush lists 1.5mil links from 1.1k domains. That ratio suggests that maybe some spammy sites link to you. Majesticseo.com suggests fewer links and more domains. I also see you are registered with ENom which has a poor reputation for spam websites. Google pays attention to registrations. The network you are hosted on seems okay. Check your back links and the ads displayed on your site. Otherwise, I do not see anything yet. There were actually 3 Google updates recently.

Comment: The updates of late are Spam 2.0, PayLoan 2.0 (may be related) and Panda 4.0. None of these seem to address cases your site fit under that I can see. What may be happening is link analysis or seeing ads on your site (if you have them) that may trigger pharmaceutical or loan keywords. I cannot testify that these sites are any good, but they do advanced link analysis for toxicity: http://linkrisk.com/ http://www.linkaudit.co.uk/ http://www.linkdetox.com/ There was a lot of positive buzz for linkdetox.com at one point. I have seen ads on sites get a site penalized. So check that too.

Comment: Also know that twitter is being used to spam Google. These sites: twitterfollowicon.com twitvalue.com were (when I looked a few weeks ago) cloaking and redirecting to an SEO site. This SEO site has had a long reputation for putting up junk domains with cloaking and redirecting to the home site. Also know that they are also using ENom as their registrar. These are two that I found, but there may be more. Is it possible that these sites were targets and your site is collateral damage? Possible. I would suggest transferring to another registrar with a good reputation such as GoDaddy ASAP!

Answer (score 2):

If you saw an immediate traffic drop then you were ***affected*** by Panda, however you may be looking at it the wrong way. Starting with Panda 1 a lot of sites were heavily penalized which opened the door for new sites to take their place in the SERPs. Now that a refresh has happened, many of the old sites that were once heavily penalized have the opportunity to move back up by fixing their own issues.

**Step 1:** Determine if your site was actually penalized, or if others just moved back into their natural positions displacing you in the SERPs.

You do this by seeing if most all pages have lost ranking, or only a few high traffic pages have moved down. If you have lost Google organic across the entire site, then you have been hit by Panda. If only a few high traffic pages lost out, then other sites have likely moved up and you moved down. It's important to figure this out before hacheting important pages from your site.

As others have said, it's not about quantity it about quality.